# How to disable middle button functionality of QTextEdit?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qtextedit

I don't want mouse middle button to paste text in my QTextEdit. This code doesn't work. `TextEdit` inherits `QTextEdit`. After mouse middle button pastes it pastes copied text.

```
void TextEdit::mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent * e ) {
    if (e->button() == Qt::MidButton) {
        e->accept();
        return;
    };
    QTextEdit::mousePressEvent(e);
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this, middle click doesn't paste any text for me.

Comment: Also, is the platform Linux by any chance?

Comment: @Merlin069 It seems that a middle click does paste on other platforms too, according to the source code of `QTextControlPrivate::mouseReleaseEvent`.

Comment: Yes I am coding under Linux

Comment: @alexisdm - That's interesting, I've never noticed that before. I ask about Linux, as it's often the default OS behaviour, unlike OSX & Windows.

Comment: look at `eventFilter` instead of `mousePressEvent`

Comment: @andre eventFilter dosn't work too

Comment: @andre `eventFilter` is only useful when you don't want or need to derive the class that would normally receive the event. But you mostly do the same thing with `eventFilter` than with the `...Event` virtual functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mouse clicks are usually registered when the button is released, you should redefine the `mouseReleaseEvent` function.

You don't even need to redefine `mousePressEvent`, because the middle button isn't handled at all by that function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using Linux here; right clicking in the window is likely to be triggering an insertion of mime data before you get to handle the mouse event, which is why it is still pasting text.

Therefore, according to Qt docs for paste: - " to modify what QTextEdit can paste and how it is being pasted, reimplement the virtual canInsertFromMimeData() and insertFromMimeData() functions."

Comment: Redefining `insertFromMimeData` would also change the way drag&drop works, instead of only changing the behavior of the middle button.

Comment: @alexisdm Redefining it and checking if the middle mouse button is pressed, otherwise calling the base class function would provide the required behaviour.

Comment: I don't say it won't work, I'm just saying adding mouse handling code in a function that doesn't have anything to do with the mouse should be avoided.

Comment: It's not really handling the mouse, but reacting to its state, which happens throughout code for GUI applications.

Comment: @Merlin069 I tried what you said but when `insertFromMimeData()` is called mouse middle button is released already so I cant know if it is called from middle button click

Comment: Out of curiosity, as it's the default behaviour of the operating system and likely a feature that the user wants, why do you want to stop it in your app?

Comment: Some parts of my QTextEdit are not editable so I dont want user to paste there any text

Answer (score 0):

I've been in the same case, that is to say: having parts of my `CustomQTextEdit` required to be **non-editable**.

As I truly love the middle mouse button paste feature, I did not wanted to disable it. So, here is the (more or less quick and dirty coded) workaround I used:

```
void QTextEditHighlighter::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{

    QString prev_text;
    if (e->button() == Qt::MidButton) {
        // Backup the text as it is before middle button click
        prev_text = this->toPlainText();
        // And let the paste operation occure...
        //        e->accept();
        //        return;
    }

    // !!!!
    QTextEdit::mouseReleaseEvent(e);
    // !!!!

    if (e->button() == Qt::MidButton) {

        /*
         * Keep track of the editbale ranges (up to you).
         * My way is a single one range inbetween the unique
         * tags "//# BEGIN_EDIT" and "//# END_EDIT"...
         */
        QRegExp begin_regexp = QRegExp("(^|\n)(\\s)*//# BEGIN_EDIT[^\n]*(?=\n|$)");
        QRegExp end_regexp  = QRegExp("(^|\n)(\\s)*//# END_EDIT[^\n]*(?=\n|$)");

        QTextCursor from = QTextCursor(this->document());
        from.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start);

        QTextCursor cursor_begin = this->document()->find(begin_regexp, from);
        QTextCursor cursor_end = this->document()->find(end_regexp, from);
        cursor_begin.movePosition(QTextCursor::EndOfBlock);
        cursor_end.movePosition(QTextCursor::StartOfBlock);
        int begin_pos = cursor_begin.position();
        int end_pos = cursor_end.position();

        if (!(cursor_begin.isNull() || cursor_end.isNull())) {
            // Deduce the insertion index by finding the position
            // of the first character that changed between previous
            // text and the current "after-paste" text
            int insert_pos; //, end_insert_pos;
            std::string s_cur = this->toPlainText().toStdString();
            std::string s_prev = prev_text.toStdString();

            int i_max = std::min(s_cur.length(), s_prev.length());
            for (insert_pos=0; insert_pos < i_max; insert_pos++) {
                if (s_cur[insert_pos] != s_prev[insert_pos])
                    break;
            }
            // If the insertion point is not in my editable area: just restore the 
            // text as it was before the paste occured
            if (insert_pos < begin_pos+1 || insert_pos > end_pos) {
                // Restore text (ghostly)
                ((MainWindow *)this->topLevelWidget())->disconnect(this, SIGNAL(textChanged()), ((MainWindow *)this->topLevelWidget()), SLOT(on_textEdit_CustomMacro_textChanged()));
                this->setText(prev_text);
                ((MainWindow *)this->topLevelWidget())->connect(this, SIGNAL(textChanged()), ((MainWindow *)this->topLevelWidget()), SLOT(on_textEdit_CustomMacro_textChanged()));
            }
        }
    }

}
```